# Notifications with Parse

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I am creating (and deleting) like notifications with Parse and am getting this message in my console:
liked
2016-03-22 20:22:04.850 myapp[3081:645612] -[myapp.feedVC refresh:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd4db725300

I have been able to create other instances where the notifications are sending and updating fine in Parse but for some reason this notification is giving me problems...no idea why. Thanks for any help or direction in advance.

```
 let object = PFObject(className: "likes")
            object["by"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
            object["to"] = uuidLbl.text
            object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if success {
                    print("liked")
                    self.likeBtn.setTitle("like", forState: .Normal)
                    self.likeBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "like.png"), forState: .Normal)

                    // send notification if we like to refresh tableView
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("liked", object: nil)

                    // send notification as like
                    if self.usernameBtn.titleLabel?.text != PFUser.currentUser()?.username {
                        let newsObj = PFObject(className: "news")
                        newsObj["by"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
                        newsObj["ava"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("ava") as! PFFile
                        newsObj["to"] = self.usernameBtn.titleLabel!.text
                        newsObj["owner"] = self.usernameBtn.titleLabel!.text
                        newsObj["uuid"] = self.uuidLbl.text
                        newsObj["type"] = "like"
                        newsObj["checked"] = "no"
                        newsObj.saveEventually()
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: I'd search your codebase for `refresh` - either you're calling `refresh` on an instance of `feedVC` yourself, or Parse is doing it for you.

Comment: yep, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd search your codebase for `refresh` - either you're calling refresh on an instance of `feedVC` yourself, or Parse is doing it for you.